# Regex to replace + with _plus in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to replace the + character from a service response to a _plus. So far I've got the following which works when the response contains a '+', but doesn't return anything when its anything else, like 'hello':

```
my $response = 'hello';   

my $find = '+';
my $replace = '_plus';

$response =~ s/\Q$find\E/$replace/g;

print Data::Dumper::Dumper($response);
```

I get the error 'Useless use of private variable in void context' when the response is something else.

I just want to return it normally if it doesn't contain any + character.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `perl -e 'my $response = "hello"; my $find = q(+); my $replace = "_plus"; $response =~ s/\Q$find\E/$replace/g; print $response'` prints `hello` with no error or warnings even if `strict` and `warnings` are turned on.  I think there might be some wider context you're not mentioning.  (For example, what does `$stripChars` have to do with anything?)

Comment: Where is `$stripChars` defined?

Comment: $stripChars line was meant to be:
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($response);

Comment: There's no wider context. The service returns a string and If that string contains a character such as +, I want to replace it with _plus. Is that not clear?

Comment: Re "There's no wider context", Yes, there is. 1) The code you posted doesn't even enable warnings, so you wouldn't get that message even if you made the error it mentions, and 2) the code you posted does not contain the error that causes that warning.

Comment: You're getting bogged down by specifics. I posted all the code necessary for the question to be answered so I can learn how to do a regex find/replace properly. Warnings and strict are enabled for more info.

Comment: Re. "I posted all the code necessary for the question to be answered" No, you didn't. As Sean and ikegami already explained, running the code you posted generates no warnings. Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run on our own machines to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not contain the error that causes that warning.

The warning is issued when when an expression consisting of a lexical variable is used in void context.

```
$ perl -we'my $x; $x;'
Useless use of private variable in void context at -e line 1.
```

The following is what the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) has to say about this warning:

> **Useless use of %s in void context**
>
> (W void) You did something without a side effect in a context that does nothing with the return value, such as a statement that doesn't return a value from a block, or the left side of a scalar comma operator. Very often this points not to stupidity on your part, but a failure of Perl to parse your program the way you thought it would. For example, you'd get this if you mixed up your C precedence with Python precedence and said
>
> ```
> $one, $two = 1, 2;
> ```
>
> when you meant to say
>
> ```
> ($one, $two) = (1, 2);
> ```
>
> Another common error is to use ordinary parentheses to construct a list reference when you should be using square or curly brackets, for example, if you say
>
> ```
> $array = (1,2);
> ```
>
> when you should have said
>
> ```
> $array = [1,2];
> ```
>
> The square brackets explicitly turn a list value into a scalar value, while parentheses do not. So when a parenthesized list is evaluated in a scalar context, the comma is treated like C's comma operator, which throws away the left argument, which is not what you want. See perlref for more on this.
>   This warning will not be issued for numerical constants equal to 0 or 1 since they are often used in statements like
>
> ```
> 1 while sub_with_side_effects();
> ```
>
> String constants that would normally evaluate to 0 or 1 are warned about.